# How does java recognise where the end of the array is?

Tags: java

If someone creates an array with 0 elements would java just make a stack variable pointing to nowhere? If we make an array with 1 element will the data structure actually contain 1 element or similar to C++ at the last (out of bounds) spot it contains '\0' ?

Comment: Java arrays have a `length` property that stores the length of the array. Memory-wise, an array object consists of the object header, the length value and the array values, but that's just conceptually, because the JVM is free to store objects in memory in any way it wants. Java does not end arrays or strings with a zero value.

Comment: Yes, `new int[0]` gives a reference to an array. Typically each array has a length field internally.

Comment: In C++, only for Char array i.e. string , the last spot contains '\0' and not in any other type of array i.e integer, float etc. In java , there is no concept of '\0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int array[] = new int[0];
```

Though it have zero elements inside it, you just created an array object called `array` in the heap/stack.

Coming to recognize the end of an array there is property called length for array objects.

[image]

```
 System.out.println(array.length); // array element count
```

Image source and more about arrays  :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html